# Hyperledger Composer how to increase execution timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have developed a business network and I have a transaction that takes more than 30s to complete.
It always crashes with this Error:

> Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer
>   comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT Response from attempted
>   peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT.

If I make the transaction to take less than 30s it runs with no problem. The transaction calls an external API with HTTP GET using the request library. The delay is on the HTTP server side, so I cannot eliminate it in practice.

I have tried to add `"grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 600000` in `connection.json` both in Peer and Orderer. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are running this problem when you invoke the submitTransaction function on the SDK?

If you want you can try with this connection options:

```
let connectionOptions = {
        identity: USER_ID,
        wallet: wallet,
        discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true },
        eventHandlerOptions: {
             strategy: null
             }
         }

    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions)
```

In this way it should be faster, but you don't use the connectionListener.

Comment: I will try it. I submit transactions through the rest api and through the composer - playground. If I don't use composer I don't have timeout problem. I forgot to say that I have changed the peers execution timeout in docker-compose file.